# Nothing happen after a command mount -t (worked before)

Tags: mount, cifs

I'm having a weird problem. I used to run the mount command manually to link a folder on my PLEX server with a folder on my NAS. It was fine until yesterday, but I had to halt the PLEX server and when I tried to mount the directory again nothing happened. It asked me for the `su` password and that's all.

Here's the relevant line from my `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.1.2/Series_TV /home/cidou/Series_TV cifs _netdev,credentials=/home/cidou/.smbcredentials     0     0
//192.168.1.2/films /home/cidou/Films cifs _netdev,credentials=/home/cidou/.smbcredentials     0     0
```

I tried this command too:

```
 sudo mount -t smbfs //192.168.1.2/Films /home/cidou/Films -o user=myname,password=mypass,sec=ntlm --verbose
```

I run an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
 uname -a
Linux plex 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 15:31:16 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

had to use the following NFS command to make it work

```
192.168.1.2:/volume1/Films /home/user/Films nfs defaults,user,auto,noatime,intr 0 0
```